# Whats the point of pkg.module (.esm.js) in package.json using rollup.js

Tags: javascript, module, package.json, rollupjs

After reading these two posts:

https://2ality.com/2017/04/setting-up-multi-platform-packages.html https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg

Is still no clear for me the point of exporting a ESM module such a

> `"module": "dist/dop.esm.js",`

If my library is written as ESM doesn't make sense to export it to src?

> `"module": "src/index.js",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases yes. But if your source code is split across several modules, it's better to expose a bundle of those modules to consumers of your library. That's because some (ahem) less efficient bundlers won't do as good a job of combining those modules, adding extra bytes. And if your library is to be consumed in a browser, it's better if the browser can make a single request rather than a request for each source module (this is still true with HTTP/2).

There's also the case where your source code is importing non-JS files (such as JSON or TypeScript) that needs to be processed by a Rollup plugin — it's much easier to handle that at the library level than to expect consumers of your library to maintain the correct configuration.